# How to program my own arrays and lists

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have to program several different types of binary trees. However, I'm not allowed to use utils such as arrays or collections. It is suggested to build my own array, should there be a need for it. The problem is, I don't even know where to start with this. How could I build, say, a 2D array?

Comment: your own array ... what do you mean? Reprogram the contiguous allocation of memory in Java? :)

Comment: If you have no idea where to start, after re-reading your lecture notes and course textbook, you should probably talk to your professor to better understand the assignment. If you are able to come up with _some_ way to start, update your question, and you will probably get help.

Comment: @vedran: I didn't downvote, but the downvote means "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: +1.  This is a student looking for help.  I think it's a valid question.  I applaud @vedran for not looking for someone to do the work for him.

Comment: +1 for `homework` tag :)

Comment: I think research effort in this context is: "show up on lectures" or at least read someone's notes... Perhaps read the litterature too...

Comment: Do you really mean you can't use arrays? That would be a huge restrictions, and elevate the assignment to much more difficult than an undergraduate course. Do you mean you can't use ArrayList?

Comment: @DJClayworth I did this many times in my undergraduate work. (Data Structures and Algorithms classes, to be specific.)  In fact, I did this in a high school AP programming class in Pascal.

Comment: @ErickRobertson Pascal is a very different language, having pointers and explicit memory allocation.

Comment: @DJClayworth Of course, but it's still a useful exercise to do in any language, and definitely appropriate for undergraduate work.

Comment: My undergrad class was required to create an implementation of an ArrayList (not of the interface, that I can recall, and without generics; they wouldn't come out for another year...) - automatic resizing, etc.  We _were_ expected to base it on the actual array type, thankfully.  Still a useful/informative exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to manually create a linked list or tree through the creation of objects which each contain a pointer to the next object in the list or tree.  This is an exercise that we did many times in our data structures class when I was in school.  Understanding how to keep the list or tree intact through inserts and deletes is a useful exercise.

```
public class ListNode<T> {
  private T payload;
  private ListNode<T> nextNode;
}

public class TreeNode<T> {
  private T payload;
  private TreeNode<T> leftChild, rightChild;
}
```

Comment: No we can't, and we can't use LinkedList as well

Comment: Note that I'm not suggesting that you use the `LinkedList` class, but rather, implement your own linked list.

Comment: @vedran specifically asked about how to build a 2D list, which is basically just a list of lists.  I updated my answer to incorporate trees or lists.  The concept is basically the same.

Answer (score 3):

You won't need arrays for building a tree. There are several books about algorithms and data structures, if you will not find what you need on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures

(answer to question: For a 2d array, create an 1d array, and store 1d arrays in a 1d array. It is possible to emulate built in arrays by creating your own linked list implementation. But it's neither effient nor what your teacher is having in mind.)

> ( inspiration for the actual question, that you don't know you are
>   asking:
>
> Something like this is the core data structure for a binary search
>   tree...
>
> ```
> class Node {
>      Object value;
>      Node left;
>      Node right;
> } )
> ```

Answer (score 1):

with a linked list. here the code: http://www.roseindia.net/java/jdk6/LinkedListExample.shtml

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Ok, everyone mentioned lists, but let's not forget that you can implement binary trees also on arrays, like heaps are implemented. So we have something like:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    private int[] tree; // assuming each node holds an integer.
    private int nodeCount;

    public BinaryTree (int nodes) {
         tree = new int[nodes * 2];
         nodeCount = nodes;
    }

    public int getRoot() {
         return tree[0];
    }

    private int getPositionOfNode(int value) {
         for(int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++) {
             if(tree[i] == value) {
                 return i;
             }
         }
         return -1;
    }

    public int getLeftChildOfNode(int node) {
         int pos = getPositionOfNode(node);
         if(pos != -1) {
              return tree[pos * 2];
         }
         return pos;
    }

    public int getRightChildOfNode(int node) {
         int pos = getPositionOfNode(node);
         if(pos != -1) {
              return tree[pos * 2 + 1];
         }
         return pos;
    }

    public int getParentOfNode(int node) {
         int pos = getPositionOfNode(node);
         if(pos != -1) {
              return tree[pos / 2];
         }
         return pos;
    }
}
```

In this structure, if a node is at position i, its children will be at positions 2*i and 2*i+1.

Comment: That is a bit too far complex for me, but I'll give it a try if I don't find a better solution.

Comment: Can you or can you not use primitive (classic) arrays?  You mentioned in a comment on my answer that you couldn't use them, but you seem to indicate here that you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TwoDArray {
   private Object[] values;
   public TwoDArray(int n, int m) {
       values = new Object[n * m];
   }
   public void set(int i, int j, Object x) { ... }
   public Object get(int i, int j) { ... }
}
public class BinTree {
   private BinTree left;
   private BinTree right;
   private Comparable value;
   public void insert(Comparable x) { ... }
}
```

Something like this?
Should not be that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by assuming that you have been forbidden from using even Java's primitive array types.  In that case, you would have to go back to the very basics and start managing memory yourself.  You would need to start by allocating a byte array or ByteBuffer of an appropriate size.  Access into that block of data would then be handled using what in C would be straightforward pointer math.

Example of a 1D array of 16 ints:

```
byte[] mem = new byte[16 * 4] ; // Ints are 4 bytes long

// Write a value to the 8th element of our "array"
index = 8 ;
int value = 31415926 ;
mem[4 * index + 0] = (byte)( value >> 24 ) ;
mem[4 * index + 1] = (byte)( ( value << 8 ) >> 24 ) ;
mem[4 * index + 2] = (byte)( ( value << 16 ) >> 24 ) ;
mem[4 * index + 3] = (byte)( ( value << 24 ) >> 24 ) ;
```

Reading a value out would be done be reversing the process and calculating the stored int value.

Note: The process of setting and retrieving values is easier using a ByteBuffer as it methods for getting and putting the primitive Java types into the byte array.